# can still .. about or can still .. on

Tags: grammar, prepositions, sentence-construction

I am learning the proposition, **about**, and **on**. I still need to improve my understanding. I wonder do I need to use **about** or **on** with the word **information**.

For example,

> The method A can still give further information about the model.
>
> The method A can still give further information on the model.

I feel **on** is awkward, however, I surprise why I cannot use **of** or **for**.

Which sentence is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to say *why* some prepositions are used and others aren't. I think it just comes down to what people have settled on.

You're right that these aren't used:

> information of the model
>   information for the model

However, both of these are fine:

> information about the model
>   information on the model

But if you feel *on* is awkward, just use *about*.

There are some other words that could be used, but they either wouldn't be as common or they would be used in more specific contexts:

> information regarding the model
>   information with respect to the model
>   information pertaining to the model
>   information relevant to the model

---

Note that in your example sentences, I would drop *the* and *still*. Also, both *provide* and *more* would be more natural words to use.

Putting all of that together:

> Method A can provide more information about the model.